# Dying Blueberries - Burned Leaves

Tags: leaves, potting-soil, blueberries

I bought 2 blueberries about 8 months ago and they summer in Cyprus was really long and they seem damaged.

Both of them are planned with soil of 4.5 to 5.5ph and watered with normal tap water. They started showing signs of burned leaves since July but i thought was normal due to the heat.

Now i dont see any new growth and am worried that they will die.

What are your suggestions?

Thank you in advance
Sakis

[image]

[image]

Plant 2:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you fertilize it? Wondering if it's nutrient burn. The young leaves are a little chlorotic.

Comment: Were there any breaks in your watering schedule? How often did you water, and approximately how much water did you apply at each watering? Did anyone use any herbicides near the blueberries? Like  @GrahamChiu, I was wondering whether you had fertilized - especially if you had used a foliar fertilizer. If you did fertilize, with what type of fertilizer? How much did you use? How soon after planting dd you use it? Looks to me like your problem is irregular/too little watering, fertilizer, or herbicide drift.

Comment: @Graham Chiu No I didn't fertilise them

Comment: @Jurp They might had in summer 1-2 days without water because I was away. I water them on a daily basis and I add around 1-2 liter of water. They are located away from any neighbours trees so I believe not. They weird thing is that bluejay strain is stronger. So far no new growth and leaves are falling after completely turning brown

Comment: I have a lantana in a pot that I've brought inside the house for the winter (it was probably watered every 2 or 3 days while outside). I didn't water it for about a week after I brought it in and all the leaves dried and fell off in abiout 3 days (it's still alive, though). I think you would have killed the berries much quicker if you under-watered. Any use of herbicides or insecticides near the plants?